# What is the reason for the appearance - object url is not defined?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I create the WordPress registration form by processing data through AJAX.But faced with the problem:

By clicking on the authorization button an error occurs in the console: *object url is not defined*

Here is my code in function.php

```
$translation_array = array( 'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce') );
wp_localize_script('ajax_event', 'object_url', $translation_array);
```

And here is my js code:

```
 jQuery('#login-form button').on('click',function(e){
    
        var username = jQuery('#login-form').find('input[name=email]').val();
        var password = jQuery('#login-form').find('input[name=password]').val();
        data = {
            'action': 'ginmagtheme_login',
            'user_login': username,
            'user_password': password,
        }
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url: object_url.url,
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                window.location.href = "/profile/";
            }
        });
     e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see any errors here. Please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has say in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) :

> Works only if the script has already been added.

Did you have a `wp_enqueue_script('ajax_event', ..., ...);` before the `wp_localize_script` ?